# Embed HTML image via iframe onto Sharepoint

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint

I'm trying to embed an "clickable" image (Html code with links and shapes in it) to a new style sharepoint site. As the new one doesn't feature the option to edit the source code I tried to embed it via an iframe and the embed webpart. I managed to get some html code in the iframe via the srcdoc attribute but it isn't showing my image. The image is on the Sharepoint and the link also correct.

The Code:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<img src=https://Testsite.com/:i:/r/sites/GBPMTest1/Shared%20Documents/Pictures/SC%20EMEA%20CoE%20Stamp%20SLENDER%20neg.png" width="400" height="400" "="" src="https://Testsite.com/:i:/r/sites/GBPMTest1/Shared%20Documents/Pictures/Weltkarte%20fertig.jpg?csf=1&amp;web=1&amp;e=v7OI07"></iframe>
```

The scr attribute is for the Sharepoint, because without it it doesn't accept the code.

Is it just not possible or did I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from using the Image Web part?

Cheers

Truez

Comment: The problem is, that I want to add links to the image. For that I need the power to edit the source code and this is not possible with the image webpart, right? Because I'm only allowed to add one link.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has almost been 2 years but just in-case you still need the solution here it is:

The Solution:
Your img syntax is incorrect, you do not have a closing ">". Here is the proper syntax:

```
<iframe srcdoc="
<img src='https://Testsite.com/:i:/r/sites/GBPMTest1/Shared%20Documents/Pictures/SC%20EMEA%20CoE%20Stamp%20SLENDER%20neg.png' width='400' height='400'/>" src="https://Testsite.com/:i:/r/sites/GBPMTest1/Shared%20Documents/Pictures/Weltkarte%20fertig.jpg?csf=1&amp;web=1&amp;e=v7OI07" width="iframe width here" height="iframe height here"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to include an iframe height and width as SharePoint requires it. Also remember when embedding any html code that requires ", you need to change it to ' instead as it will break the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. The project is closed already, but I appreciate your answer! Will save this for later.